# Solution of a logarithmic and an exponential curve

Tags: analytic-geometry

> What is the least positive integral value of $k$ such that the equation $$\ln x + k = e^{x-k}$$ has a solution?

I tried plotting the two curves and concluded that the limiting value of k will be the case when $y = \ln x +k$ and $y = e^{x-k}$ touch each other. But then I could not proceed further to find the solution.

Comment: Is your equation correct? As orlp stated, the answer would be very trivial then.

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't provide a lot of insight into the *why*, but for $k=x=1$ we have:

$$\ln 1 + 1 = e^{1-1}$$
$$0 + 1 = 1$$

Since $k =1$ is the least positive integer anyways, this solution must be optimal.